# Salvar dados, desconsiderando DIV's ocultas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Em minha `View` eu possuo um select que esconde e mostra a`div` de acordo com o `select` escolhido. Esta parte, está funcionando corretamente.
Este `select` possui três opções, e o formulário muda de acordo com o valor escolhido. O problema, é que possuo campos iguais nestes formulários, e ao enviar para o `controller`, ele reconhece apenas o primeiro valor.

Um exemplo abaixo:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select#Cidade');
var cidades = document.querySelectorAll('.divcidade');

function esconder() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
        cidades[i].style.display = 'none';
    };
}

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    esconder()
    var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(id, this);
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
});

esconder();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label>Qual a sua cidade?</label>
    <select class="cat_dropdown" id="Cidade" name="Cidade">
    <option value="1">Fom 1</option>
    <option value="2">Fom 2</option>
    <option value="3">Fom 3</option>
    </select>
<div id="1" class="divcidade">    
     Nome: <input name="nome"/>
</div>

<div id="2" class="divcidade">   
     Nome: <input name="nome"/><br/> 
     Idade: <input name="idade"/>
</div>

<div id="3" class="divcidade">
     Nome: <input name="nome"/><br/>
     Idade: <input name="idade"/><br/>
     Cidade: <input name="cidade"/>
</div>
```

Para quem prefere: [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/6dhm5kLn/)

Meu problema, é que se preencher o Form 1, ele envia para meu `controller` e salva normalmente. Agora se eu preencher o form 2 ou form 3, ele envia os campos repetidos como `null`.

Minha dúvida é: Como enviar para o `controller` o `formulário` selecionado no?

E uma outra dúvida é: Estou fazendo da melhor forma? Neste exemplo o usuário terá três campos,  `Nome, Idade, Cidade`. A melhor forma de fazer é essa, deixando o campo não utilizado como `null`, ou criar três entidades, como `User1, User2, user3`, e cada uma com suas propriedades? Tipo `User1` somente com a propriedade `Nome`, o `User2` com `Nome e idade` e o `User3` com `Nome, Idade, cidade`.

Comment: Se você setar o campo como disabled ele não será enviado na requisição.

Comment: @LuisHenrique Você teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Porque você não deixa os três campos visíveis e dependendo do `select` você da `disable` em um ou mais `inputs`? Assim só teria um `form` e ficaria mais simples o submit.

Comment: @dHEKU É porque eu possuo uns 10 campos em cada div. Eu apenas reduzi o exemplo. E outra, como os campos possuem o mesmo nome e atributo, se ficar a amostra, mesmo desabilitado, recebo reclamação dos usuários do sistema.

Comment: @LuisHenrique fiz conforme a sua ideia. Porém, se alguém possuir outra alternativa melhor, ficarei feliz em utilizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a ideia do @LuisHenrique nos comentários, eu desabilitei os `inputs` das `div's` ocultas, enviando assim somente os dados necessários.

Meu script ficou desta forma:

```
<script>
    var select = document.querySelector('select#Prazo');
    var cidades = document.querySelectorAll('.divPrazo');

    function esconder() {
        for (var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
            cidades[i].style.display = 'none';
            //Desabilito aqui todos os inputs das divs
            $(".divPrazo :input").prop("disabled", true);
        };
    }

    select.addEventListener('change', function () {
        esconder();
        var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(id, this);
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        //Habilito aqui todos os inputs da div selecionada
        $("#" + id + " :input").prop("disabled", false);
    });
    esconder();
</script>
```

O restante do código permaneceu da forma que estava.